# a problem about quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Suppose there is an integer $N$ and I want to count the number of $a$s that
‎$‎‎‎‎a^2 ‎\mathop\equiv\limits^{N} b $‎‎‎‎,

when $b \in I$ for certain interval $I$ and $N$ goes to infinity.

is it almost trivial?

for example if $I= [-\frac{N \delta}{2},\frac{N \delta}{2}]$, Is the answer $|I| + O(1)$ ?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @hellotinfish :the number of $a$s.